# Would calling a mediator be correct in my Handler when crossing services/modules in a DDD monolith

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs, clean-architecture

### Preface about the architecture

In a microservice, this could be a service according to clean-architecture:

#### BasketService

- Api

  - Application  [CQRS]

    - Core
  - Infrastructure

#### CatalogService

- Api

  - Application  [CQRS]

    - Core
  - Infrastructure

But since i'm applying DDD to a monolith, i can currently remove my Api layer and have less "projects"/module. So every module ( eg. basket and catalog) contains 3 projects currently:

- Application

  - Core
- Infrastructure

Both have a dependency on .Core

### Problem description

My application has a BasketModule and a CatalogModule.
Would it be correct to get information from the CatalogModule ( which contains the products) with Mediator like this:

```
public Task<BasketDTO> Handle(GetBasketByBuyerIdCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        BasketDTO result;
        var basket = m_basketRepo.GetById(request.BuyerId);

        if (basket == null)
        {
            result = new BasketDTO()
            {
                BuyerId = request.BuyerId,
                Items = new List<BasketItem>()
            };
            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }

        //Could be automapper, but not now currently //ignore
        var products = new List<DTO.Product>();

        foreach (var item in basket.Items)
        {
          var product = m_mediator.Send(new GetProductByIdQuery(item.ProductId)).Result; //ignore the non-async. It's example code 

            products.Add(new DTO.Product()
            {
                Id = product.Id,
                Price = product.Price,
                Title = product.Title
            });
        }

        result = new BasketDTO()
        {
            BuyerId = basket.BuyerId,
            Items = basket.Items
            .Select(dl => new DTO.BasketItem()
            {

                ProductId = dl.ProductId,
                Quantity = dl.Quantity,
                Product = products
                .Where(cl => cl.Id == dl.ProductId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList()
        };

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

It is about the following line:

```
 var product = await m_mediator.Send(new GetProductByIdQuery(item.ProductId));
```

Is this correct to do? I'm not talking about the rest of the example code, but specifically about calling the mediator to get the product and having a dependency of the project "Basket.Application" on "Catalog.Application"

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, only you know the answer to your question. By the looks of it and despite the naming "GetBasketByBuyerIdCommand" it seems you're only running queries in your code. So that means you're only working on the "Q" of CQRS and on that perspective what you are doing is fine.

In my opinion, the answer to your question lies in the rest of your architecture and especially in what you're trying to achieve with it at this point. If you want your BasketModule and CatalogModule to be totally independent somewhere down the road, this type of choice taken now might have a great deal of impact in the future.

For example, if you, later on, want the two modules to be separated into two different microservices, you will have to come up with a different way of doing the query you described. How to handle this is a whole new conversation in its own respect.

Comment: Upvoted solely because you noticed that I named it Command and it should be Query.

I'm still checking the answers for assessing what i should do next.

Thanks for noticing :)

Answer (score 0):

The mean role of a mediator is to decouple the presentation layer from the application services and do some default treatments using middlewares, rather than communicating between bounded contexts.

Thus I would prefer to have a mediator per bounded context :)

To integrate the two BCs you can add an interface of GetProductByIdQuery to the Basket domain (or application) layer and have its implementation in Basket/infra.

The implementation of GetProductByIdQuery (considered as a secondary adapter) may call the mediator of Catalog's BC, and transform the result to preserve the ubiquitous language.

IMHO, This will keep the monolith clean and reduce the migration cost if you decide to split some parts of it i.e only the secondary adapter implementation will change to do some inter-process communication instead.

PS: I'm not really familiar with clean architecture, but I consider it a more featured version of the Hexagonal one..